# SQL Server / SSMS - Error Converting nvarchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, variable-types

I have checked `Temp_Calc_1` against `Temp_Calc_2` and they both have the same column datatypes (`float`, `nvarchar(255)`) and are in the same order when reading down the table. When I try to run this on the empty `Temp_Calc_2`, I get an error:

> Error converting nvarchar to float

on the line `INSERT INTO dbo.Temp_Calc_2`

```
USE MfgMetrics                                  

INSERT INTO dbo.Temp_Calc_2         
    SELECT 
        zps.[Plant], [Work Center], 
        [Scheduled start Date], [SCHEDULE START TIME],
        [SCHEDULED FINISHED DATE], [SCHEDULED FINISHED TIME],
        [MATERIAL NUMBER], [MATERIAL DESCRIPTON],
        [ORDER NUMBER], [ORDER TYPE], 
        [PLANNED QUANTITY], [PLANNED QTY - PROD UN],
        [DELIVERED QTY], [DELIVERED QTY - PROD UN],
        [RemainingQty(BUn)], [REMAINING QTY - Prod Un],
        [COMMITED QTY], [COMMITED QTY  - PROD UN], [UOM],
        [STORAGE LOCATION], [COMMENTS],
        [RATE QUANTITY], [RATE QUANTITY - PROD UN], [RATE HOUR],
        [OPERATING EFFIECIENCY], [UNIT],
        [STD UNITS / HR], [STD UNITS / HR - PROD UN], [UOM2],
        [ORDER STATUS], [ACTUAL START DATE], [ACTUAL START TIME],
        [MRP CONTROLLER], [CREATED ON], [TIME CREATED],
        [CHANGED ON], [TIME CHANGE], 
        [ORDER TEXT LINES], [ORDER TEXT 2nd LINE], [FileDate],
        scf.[OQ_RxnTime_(mins)], scf.[RunDurThreshold_(hrs)],
        CASE 
           WHEN (zps.[MATERIAL NUMBER] LIKE '%.%') 
              THEN zps.[MATERIAL NUMBER] 
           WHEN ISNUMERIC(zps.[MATERIAL NUMBER]) = 1 
              THEN CAST(CAST(zps.[MATERIAL NUMBER] AS INT) AS NVARCHAR(255))
           ELSE zps.[MATERIAL NUMBER] 
        END As [Material],
        (CAST(CAST(zps.[ORDER NUMBER] AS INT) AS NVARCHAR(255)) + '_' + CAST(CAST(zps.[PLANNED QUANTITY] AS INT) AS NVARCHAR(255))) AS Order_Quantity,
        scf.[OQ_RxnTime_(mins)] * zps.[STD UNITS / HR] / 60 AS OQWindow
    FROM 
        Temp_Calc_1 zps 
    INNER JOIN
        SAWorkCenters swc ON zps.Plant = swc.Plant
                          AND zps.[Work Center] = swc.WCGroup
    INNER JOIN
        SchedAttCalcFactors scf ON zps.Plant = scf.[Plant Code]
    ORDER BY 
        zps.Plant, zps.[Work Center], zps.[ORDER NUMBER], zps.FileDate 
GO
```

Comment: Seems like an insert column data type doesn't match the selected data type.

Comment: Usually this error occurs when a null value is tried to get converted, are you sure there is no null value you are trying to convert?

Comment: I don't see how this is diagnosable without examples of the data going through this query.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. @ Jarlh The data types show that they all match... so I am not sure that is it, but I'll keep an open mind and recheck once more. @ Eray Balkanli There are null values in the table, so I will try to omit them or find a way to skip them when running the calculation part. @ underscore_d I do apologize for not providing more data. It is a work project so I am unable to release anything more than the code lines, unfortunately.

Comment: 2 things i can add, always indicate the column order when doing insert into, and try to do the select without the insert. If it doesn't fail then you have a theoretically float that isn't float.

Comment: ISNumeric is no real guarantee - search the internet for discussions and suggestions. The case expression that involves this is also problematic and it is my suspicion that this is the source of the problem. To verify, try your select statement (w/o the insert) and comment out that column express.  And quite frankly, your usage of double casting is freaky.

Comment: Thank you @ Ezequiel and @ SMor! I will look into both of those. I appreciate everyone's help.